# Nginx routing issue - http server and https server

Tags: nginx, devops

I have two nginx files in my sites-available. One is for a https domain and another for and http domain. I have the routing for the https domain to route `domain1.com` to `https://www.domain1.com`, but instead, it routes to the http domain I have set up, `http://www.domain2.com`. Can anybody help me out? I've tried google the issue but nothing has help so far.

domain1 setup

```
server{
    server_name http://domain1.com
    return 301 https://www.domain1.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen  443 ssl;
    server_name www.domain1.com;

    ssl_certificate      /home/node/www.domain1.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/node/www.domain1.com.key;

    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location  / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/mainacc.log;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;
    }
}
```

domain2 setup

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the listen 80 directive at top of your domain1 setup block

this should work

```
server {
    listen  80 ;
    listen  [::]:80 ;
    server_name domain1.com, www.domain1.com;
    # return 301 https://www.domain1.com$request_uri;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.domain1.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Did this do the trick ?